# Changing background colour without increasing GPU overdraw - Android

Tags: android, background, styles

I know about using android:background to change the background colour but that adds another layer that the GPU has to draw to the app. I was wondering whether there is a way to change something to set the background for the style without adding another layer of GPU overdraw. Perhaps it could be done with a style of some sort but what I have tried with styles only seems to redraw over the top of the normal light theme background.

Comment: Change your template background if you will use same background all application

Comment: @GokhanArik Do you have any website showing how to do this or can you explain yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your res/values folder create a file and name it. For example theme.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.NoBackground" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

For the parent, use whatever theme you are using in your application manifest. The logic is that, you are extending your parent theme and setting background attribute.

In your manifest file, set your new style as application theme between `application` tags.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.NoBackground"
```

This will remove theme background, so you have to set your background for your each activity in your layouts. If you want to set one background for all application, instead of `null` assign whatever your drawable is.
Something like that

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/abc</item>
```

Romain Guy explains it in this article, I just tried to simplify for you :

http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/04/speed-up-your-android-ui/